# Jsoup--How does jsoup collect dynamic data and pull-down pagination of drop-down refresh

Tags: ios, jsoup

I've successfully implemented a drop down refresh into my rss feed so that when I pull down the UITableView, it should refresh. All is well in that sense as the date on the pull down refreshes etc. but my UITableView doesn't refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Jsoup doesn't do much in the way of dynamic data download. It issues individual HTTP get/post/put/etc requests. If you want more dynamism, htmlUnit is a more capable http client. If you need more still, a headless browser is good - PhantomJs/Selenium/etc.